# How to change Enter by Done from keyboard in a textMultiline?

Tags: android

this is my  editext:

```
EditText<br>
android:id="@+id/detailsText"<br>
android:layout_width="fill_parent"<br>
android:layout_height="wrap_content"<br>
android:inputType="textMultiLine"<br>
android:maxLength="500"/><br>
```

I have to hide the keyboard some how so y add this:
    details.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

```
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {<br>
        if (event != null&& (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {<br>
          InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
                  Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);<br>
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(details.getWindowToken(), 0);
            return true;
        }<br>
        return false;
    }
});
```

When i press enter the keyboard get hide (that's what i want), but i need to change the arrow that the enter button have by default, I want to put something like "Done" and i cant change the  `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` because the edit text change the size with the user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this
 `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` 
This will automatically hide the keyboard with done button, you don't need to manually write code for it.

Comment: But the Done button doesn't appear because i have a android:inputType="textMultiLine" and i need textMultiline. The done button appear only with android:singleLine="true"

Comment: @user2033349 remove textMultiLine and set lines=8 or more of your choice, it will show the done button, don't make the things complicated.

Comment: Thanks you are correct but that way the edit text will have a predefined height and i want to make it automatic because this edit text will have a maxLengh=500, so i want the edit text increase his height only if needed other wise how i can add a scrollbar in to the edit text?

Comment: You can add the scrollbar to your EditText by using  android:scrollbars="vertical" this attribute.